# SPM UIColor resources don't support Dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift-package-manager

I created an asset folder in my SPM package and put all UIColors my app required. I set Any and Dark appearances for each color. But when I use these colors (set in Storyboard) in my app I get only "light" mode colors. What is the point of color resources in SPM without this support?

Answer (score 0):

Assets (either images or colors) don't work well with SPM.

The problem is the following - a xib or a storyboard is stored inside a bundle (`Bundle`) and when the xib/storyboard is loaded, it also loads resources from the same bundle.

It's possible to reference a class (e.g. `UIView` subclass) in another module but there is no way to load resources from a different bundle.

This is obvious with images - the Interface builder shows images correctly but they are not loaded at runtime.
With colors it's a bit trickier - the Interface Builder shows them correctly and at first glance it seems they are loaded at runtime correctly. However, they are not. The xib/storyboard just contains a single RGB value that is used as a fallback. Both light & dark modes then use that fallback value.

By the way, this is not SPM specific, the same would happen with xcframeworks.

The only workaround I can see is having the same color assets in every package that uses them, or switching to SwiftUI.

This is unlikely to change since Interface Builder was always created more for Objective-C runtime and Swift-specific package manager just doesn't work well with it.

With old Xcode targets we could add the same asset file to multiple targets which would work but that doesn't seem possible to do with SPM.